# How to use Kusto query as input data to Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-data-explorer

I have a query from Kusto explorer which I would like to use as Azure ML input data. Is this possible?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried and how it failed so we can help you. This is a good read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no direct integration between Kusto and AML. AML can create tabular data sets from few formats (see [here](https://aka.ms/tabulardataset-api-reference)), so the simplest way would be to export from Kusto to CSV and consume it from AML

Answer (score 0):

A new release ([1.14.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/azure-machine-learning-release-notes)) of the Azure Machine Learning SDK for Python brings some support for Kusto. Check this package to figure out if it's helpful.